# PostgreSQL trigger is executing the trigger function intermittently

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
-- this is the trigger --
create trigger vrms_ave_and_irms_total_snr_monitor_trigger
    on public.snr_monitor
    for each row
    execute procedure 
    public.log_vrms_ave_and_irms_total_on_snr_monitor(); 



-- this is the stored procedure --
create or replace function 
    public.log_vrms_ave_and_irms_total_on_snr_monitor()
        return trigger as 
            $body$

            begin
                update snr_monitor as t1
                set 
                    vrms = round(cast(t2.v_average as numeric), 3),
                    irms = round(cast(t2.i_sum as numeric), 3)
                from (
                    select
                        device_id
                        rdts, 
                        avg(vrms) as v_average,
                        sum(irms) as i_sum
                    from snr_monitor
                    where phase < 3
                    group by device_id, rdts
                    order by device_id, rdts desc
                    limit 1
                ) as t2 
                where t1.device_id = t2.device_id
                and t1.rdts = t2.rdts
                and t1.phase = 3;

                return null;
            end;

            $body$

language plpgsql volatile
cost 100;
alter function public.log_vrms_ave_and_irms_total_on_snr_monitor()
owner to postgresadmin;
```

The trigger is watching on the same table where it is supposed to execute an update procedure.

It is supposed to update the row where phase is equals to 3 whenever there is an insert that happens on rows where phase is equals to 0 to 2

The trigger and its procedure is executing but some how it misses an update on some rows.

Any idea why that happens?

Comment: is your update query working individually?

Comment: yes, actually now, its working but intermittently it misses some updates at phase == 3.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name thanks, I missed to type the 'where.'